# Radio/antenna questions; bordering on off-topic

Tags: discussion

This question just showed up:

[Does Wifi signal strength affect link speed?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/51774/2028)

It's one of those borderline questions that at first glance make you want to vote to close. Then I thought, well, maybe it should be migrated to SuperUser (it's about Windows' interaction with wireless networking)...

But maybe it's more about general RF and antenna orientation, which might be better migrated to Physics. But I don't think Physics is quite as appropriate for radio spectrum questions when it clearly involves some sort of electronic circuit.

At the end of the day, I feel it's more about a consumer electronics application, not necessarily an EE challenge or problem.

Should it be addressed at all, or closed as off topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reviewed it and my personal reaction was to leave it open.  The answer has to do with how signal to noise ratio effects the data carrying capacity of a channel, which is on topic here.  If it devolves to a consumer WiFi product discussion, then I would vote to close it.

Comment: Agreed - RF/Antenna discussion is very much on topic as far as I am concerned, unless it's something like "which router should I buy?" or similar. It's unfortunate the subject mainly pops up in the form of the above type question, rather than e.g. more ham radio or RF theory type questions, which would be far more interesting (IMHO)

Answer (score 4):

Agreed wit Olin, antenna's (and the like) are part of the discipline of black art of electronics. They are really hard to understand if you don't have a lot of experience about how they work.

Don't know the proper English wording, translated from Dutch it'd be '(electric) field theory'.

Answer (score 3):

I myself saw it as more RF/MAC layer oriented, not windows configuration, so it's an engineering question.